# File.exists() returns false for service in local account

Tags: c#, windows-services, network-protocols

I have windows service which runs under local system account. I am checking File.Exist(File in the network). this works fine with User account but it return false for file.exists() in local system account. I can not run service using user account. Thanks in advance.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
  m_objLogFile.LogError("******************Servicestarted*****************", "", "");
  Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartIndexing));
  th.Start(); 
} 
private void StartIndexing() 
{ 
  bool bVal = File.Exists(@"100.100.1.1\f\Files\abc.txt"); 
}
```

Comment: Show your work first..

Comment: Check whether the LocalSystem account has the proper rights for network access (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However giving it access to network might be a security issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Impersonate your account to access the file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647248.aspx

Comment: Refer to the link. You can impersonate (run under another account other than the account the service is actually running under) user account as mentioned in the code in the link.

Answer (score 5):

The Local System account (LSA) is a machine specific account - while it is highly privileged on the machine, it doesn't by rights have any privileges on the network.

To fix this either:

- run the service under the credentials of an existing user who does have network access privileges
- or create a new lowly privileged domain account and assign it just the rights it needs, then run the service using the credentials of that user

You also cannot use `100.100.1.1\f\Files\abc.txt` as a path for a file - try prefixing it with a double backslash first: `\\100.100.1.1\f\Files\abc.txt`. Without that double backslash the OS will search for a folder called 100.100.1.1 in your current working directory. (Note that you say this works under normal user credentials - either you are mistaken or you have made a mistake when copying the code here).

Comment: It means any how i can not check it on local system account. Is it correct?

Comment: @Pratik That is correct - by good practice dictates that you shouldn't run your service using that particular account anyway - unless you really need the privileges it has.

Comment: I am using path prefix with "\\". i forgot it to add. Now I am switching it to user account as I read lots of forums and as per you say I don't have other option. Thanks.

Comment: @Pratik No problems. Impersonation isn't going to solve your issue for a normal windows service (you don't have a caller or invoker), so I'm not sure why you marked the other answer.